# How come my label is unclickable?

Tags: c#, label

I'm trying to create a project in c# , mainly a memory game. It was all going pretty well till i came upon an issue that i haven't seen anyone else have and that really baffles me since i don't think i'm doing anything really complicated. On my "Form" are 16 labels , all with a single method on click. When i run my program , the click part never happens. The buttons work fine and the line-by-line debug starts when they are clicked on.But on the labels it just does nothing , never calls it.Here are a few things that might be needed:

### Forum1.Designer.cs*

```
namespace MatchingGame1
{
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label9 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label10 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label11 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label12 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label13 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label14 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label15 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label16 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(567, 57);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 69);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "Start";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Enabled = false;
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(570, 152);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 81);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button2.Text = "Hide";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Visible = false;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this.label5.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 129);
        this.label5.Name = "label5";
        this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label5.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label5.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this.label7.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(271, 129);
        this.label7.Name = "label7";
        this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label7.TabIndex = 6;
        this.label7.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label7.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label9
        // 
        this.label9.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label9.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 256);
        this.label9.Name = "label9";
        this.label9.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label9.TabIndex = 8;
        this.label9.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label9.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label10
        // 
        this.label10.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label10.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 256);
        this.label10.Name = "label10";
        this.label10.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label10.TabIndex = 9;
        this.label10.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label10.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label11
        // 
        this.label11.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(271, 256);
        this.label11.Name = "label11";
        this.label11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label11.TabIndex = 10;
        this.label11.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label11.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label12
        // 
        this.label12.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label12.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 256);
        this.label12.Name = "label12";
        this.label12.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label12.TabIndex = 11;
        this.label12.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label12.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label13
        // 
        this.label13.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label13.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 383);
        this.label13.Name = "label13";
        this.label13.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 127);
        this.label13.TabIndex = 12;
        this.label13.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label13.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label14
        // 
        this.label14.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label14.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 383);
        this.label14.Name = "label14";
        this.label14.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 127);
        this.label14.TabIndex = 13;
        this.label14.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label14.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label15
        // 
        this.label15.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label15.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(271, 383);
        this.label15.Name = "label15";
        this.label15.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 127);
        this.label15.TabIndex = 14;
        this.label15.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label15.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label16
        // 
        this.label16.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label16.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 383);
        this.label16.Name = "label16";
        this.label16.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 127);
        this.label16.TabIndex = 15;
        this.label16.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label16.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this.label6.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 129);
        this.label6.Name = "label6";
        this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label6.TabIndex = 5;
        this.label6.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label6.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 2);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(138, 2);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(271, 2);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label3.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this.label4.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 2);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 3;
        this.label4.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label8
        // 
        this.label8.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 129);
        this.label8.Name = "label8";
        this.label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 125);
        this.label8.TabIndex = 7;
        this.label8.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label8.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.None;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 4;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label8, 3, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label13, 0, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label14, 1, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label15, 2, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label16, 3, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label12, 3, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label11, 2, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label10, 1, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label9, 0, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label5, 0, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label6, 1, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label7, 2, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label4, 3, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label3, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label2, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(534, 512);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(671, 512);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Matching Game";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label9;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label10;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label11;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label12;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label13;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label14;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label15;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label16;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;

}
```

}

### Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace MatchingGame1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random random = new Random();
    private List<Image> takeIm()
    {
        string directory = @".\";
        List<Image> ImageList = new List<Image>();
        foreach (string myFile in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.jpg",            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            ImageList.Add(Image.FromFile(myFile));
            ImageList.Add(Image.FromFile(myFile));
        }
        return ImageList;
    }


    private void AssignImagesToSquares(List<Image> a)
    {
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label imageLabel = control as Label;
            if (imageLabel != null)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(a.Count);
                imageLabel.Image = a[randomNumber];
                a.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    } 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;
        clickedLabel.Visible = true;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Image> a = new List<Image>();
        a = takeIm();
        AssignImagesToSquares(a);
        button2.Visible = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button1.Visible = false;
        button1.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label imageLabel = control as Label;
            imageLabel.Visible = false;
        }

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Is there anything overlaying those controls that could be trapping the click? Also, `Label` is not usually used as an interactive control, so you may want to reconsider the UX aspect of that.

Comment: what happens/is supposed to happen in the event?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET If all else fails , i will try it all again with buttons this time. But it struck me as pretty odd

Comment: I don't think there is anything that prevents `Click` from firing off a Label control, hence my assumption that something else (like a panel) is overlaying them. Still a weird control choice.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or Web Forms?  That will make a huge difference on the possible causes.

Comment: @LarsTech it already is pretty small , i don't think i can make it simpler that what i have made since i tried to isolate the problem in order to find out what is wrong

Comment: @SteveDanner Windows Forms

Comment: Show where in the code you put event handler attaching. May be it never been attached

Comment: @Plutonix normally it would make the label invisible but as it stands it just prints something.Or it would if the "Click" call happened at all.the step by step i try and do frequently to see what goes on and it points to when clicking , literally nothing happens

Comment: please show the rest of this: `private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: cannot reproduce - works perfectly for me

Comment: I will post the whole code here and if any of you guys can make sense of it...Since another (in this case Plutonix , thanks for putting the effort mate) can't reproduce it i don't know what else to say. Here goes nothing

Comment: While trying to make sense of it i'm still experimenting so a few things changed here and there in the last hour. My last edit is the latest one. Sorry about that. So when you guys run it , when you click the label after the "start" and "hide" buttons , the image appears? Edit: Realised you guys don't have the images truly stupid of me...and again sorry

Comment: I have no idea what the start and hide buttons are.  When I click one of 2 lables attached to the same handler, the one clicked disappears just like the code is written

Comment: I replaced your random image stuff with `imageLabel.Image = SystemIcons.Application.ToBitmap();` and changed your click event to `clickedLabel.Visible = false;`, and everything works fine.

Comment: Replaced the image by copying your example , changed click event to 'Console.WriteLine("m");' in order to make it simpler. After the images dissapear , i click and nothing comes on the output window. I guess there something wrong with my system/compiler? Thanks for the time and effort , i guess i will go with buttons after all

Comment: If control property `Visible` set to `false` - you cannot click on it. So your code in then event handler `clickedLabel.Visible = true;` seems useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your labels was hidden before you try click on it

Control will not fire event `Click` if property `Visible` set to `false`.

If you want show/hidden control by clicking on it, then try to play with background color or picture in the control.
`Hidden` - no picture/transparent
`Visible` - picture or some background color will be shown